# Output of string in for loop changes depending on whether a certain condition is met

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, vector, tokenize

I've been trying to tokenize a string in C++.
I have a `for` loop that I'm using to iterate over the string, as seen below:

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i < data_str.length(); i++)
{
    tok += data_str[i];
    if(tok[i] == '\n')
    {
        //cout << "NEWLINE" << endl;
        tok = "";
    }
    if(tok == "output:")
    {
        cout << "OUTPUT FOUND" << endl;
        tokens.push_back("output:");
        tok = "";
    }
    cout << tok << endl;
}
```

As you can see I'm resetting the `tok` variable when a certain token ("output:") is found. I then add a string to a vector I'm using to store my tokens, called `tokens`. To see if my tokens vector had the appropriate amount of strings, I printed it out. I expected two strings, each saying "output:". However, when the vector was printed, it only had one string. I did a little debugging, and found that whenever I try to reset the `tok` variable after finding the token "output:" the loop only finds one occurrence of the string "output:". I then decided to print the `tok` variable, and got the following output:

```
o
ou
out
outp
outpu
output
OUTPUT FOUND

"
"H
"He
"Hel
"Hell
"Hello
"Hello
"Hello W
"Hello Wo
"Hello Wor
"Hello Worl
"Hello World
"Hello World"
"Hello World"

"Hello World"
o
"Hello World"
ou
"Hello World"
out
"Hello World"
outp
"Hello World"
outpu
"Hello World"
output
"Hello World"
output:
"Hello World"
output:"
"Hello World"
output:"G
"Hello World"
output:"Go
"Hello World"
output:"Goo
"Hello World"
output:"Good
"Hello World"
output:"Goody
"Hello World"
output:"Goodye
"Hello World"
output:"Goodye
"Hello World"
output:"Goodye W
"Hello World"
output:"Goodye Wo
"Hello World"
output:"Goodye Wor
"Hello World"
output:"Goodye Worl
"Hello World"
output:"Goodye World
"Hello World"
output:"Goodye World"
output:string
```

When I commented out the line that reset the `tok` variable I got:

```
o
ou
out
outp
outpu
output
OUTPUT FOUND
output:
output:"
output:"H
output:"He
output:"Hel
output:"Hell
output:"Hello
output:"Hello
output:"Hello W
output:"Hello Wo
output:"Hello Wor
output:"Hello Worl
output:"Hello World
output:"Hello World"

o
ou
out
outp
outpu
output
OUTPUT FOUND
output:
output:"
output:"G
output:"Go
output:"Goo
output:"Good
output:"Goody
output:"Goodye
output:"Goodye
output:"Goodye W
output:"Goodye Wo
output:"Goodye Wor
output:"Goodye Worl
output:"Goodye World
output:"Goodye World"
output:string
output:string
```

TWhy does my loop correctly work only when I'm not trying to reset the `tok` variable? I have to reset the variable, otherwise other parts of my program wouldn't work. Is there an alternative solution for resetting my `tok` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious that `tok` is a `std::string`, so:

```
for(unsigned int i=0; i < data_str.length(); i++)
    {
        tok += data_str[i];
        if(tok[i] == '\n')
        {
            //cout << "NEWLINE" << endl;
            tok = "";
        }
```

Let's use paper and pencil, and follow along just this part of the parsing algorithm. Assuming that `data_str` consists of the following text:

```
"hello\nworld"
```

After `data_str[5]` gets appended to `tok`, so that `tok` now contains `"hello\n"`, since `tok[5]` is `'\n'`, tok gets cleared to an empty string.

On the next iteration, `data_str[6]` gets appended to an empty `tok`, so `tok` now contains just a "w" (since it was cleared on the previous iteration of the loop).

```
 if(tok[i] == '\n')
```

`i` is now 6. This checks `tok[6]`. Of course, `tok` has only one character. This results in undefined behavior, and meaningless result.

Things go pretty much off the rails, from this point forward.

If the intent here is to clear the `tok` buffer after every newline, check the last character of `tok`, which would be `tok[tok.size()-1]`, instead of `tok[i]`, since `i` and the size of `tok` have absolutely nothing to do with each other, whatsoever.

Comment: Or use `data_str[i]`.